# Sequelize: Using "where" inside a child include overrides parent's "where" criteria. Composite primary key involved

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

So,

I have two tables, with a 1:M relationship. They have in common two primary keys: tenant and user_id.

I have defined the model relationship and btw, I am not sure if I did it correctly because I am still not sure how to handle composite primary keys on Sequelize. This works well with my many other queries, and I think it influences the problem.

```
// Sequelize model set-up:
const user = serviceLayerDB.define('user',
    { // Database columns:
        tenant: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(45),
            primaryKey: true
        },
        user_id: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(24),
            primaryKey: true
        },
        status: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(11)
        }
    });

const user_component = serviceLayerDB.define('user_component',
    { // Database columns:
        tenant: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(45),
            primaryKey: true
        },
        user_id: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(24),
            primaryKey: true
        },
        component_id: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(24),
            primaryKey: true
        },
        active: {
            type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
        }
    });


// Sequelize relationship set-up:
user.hasMany(user_component, { foreignKey: 'user_id' });
user.hasMany(user_component, { foreignKey: 'tenant' });
```

BUT **the problem** comes when I have the following query:

```
// Retrieving user and related components.
function getSubscriptions() {
        let options = {
            where: {
                tenant: 'company_A',
                user_id: '1001'
            },
            include: [{ // Adding components, filtered by "active" value:
                model: user_component,
                where: {
                    active: 1
                },
                required: false
            }]
        };

        user.findAll(options)
            .then(function(data) {
                if (data.length === 0) { // If no data found:
                    console.log('No data found');
                    return;
                }

                // Curate Sequelize result:
                let curatedData = data.map(function(userInstance) { return userInstance.get({ plain: true}) }); // Workaround to be able to perform .get().
                console.log(JSON.stringify(curatedData, null, 2));
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('critical', 'Failed to find data in database. Error: ' + error);
            })
}


// Execute:
getSubscriptions();
```

What I want is to find the user and its components, but only the ones with the active value set to 1. It is not working: **the result is every component with the value active set to 1 under the same "tenant", the child include is ignoring the "user_id" that we indicated in the parent**.

Am I right to think this is related to my composite primary key? How to fix this in the most elegant manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use aliases when you associate a model to another model more then once.
For instance:

```
user.hasMany(user_component, { foreignKey: 'user_id', as: 'UserComponents' });
user.hasMany(user_component, { foreignKey: 'tenant', as: 'TenantComponents' });
```

And afterwards you should decide for what exact association you wish to do an include operation:
the association by **user_id** field

```
let options = {
            where: {
                tenant: 'company_A',
                user_id: '1001'
            },
            include: [{ // Adding components, filtered by "active" value:
                model: user_component,
                as: 'UserComponents'
                where: {
                    active: 1
                },
                required: false
            }]
        };
```

the association by **tenant** field

```
let options = {
            where: {
                tenant: 'company_A',
                user_id: '1001'
            },
            include: [{ // Adding components, filtered by "active" value:
                model: user_component,
                as: 'TenantComponents'
                where: {
                    active: 1
                },
                required: false
            }]
        };
```

If you would like both child collections with the **active: 1** condition you can do this:

```
let options = {
            where: {
                tenant: 'company_A',
                user_id: '1001'
            },
            include: [{ // Adding components, filtered by "active" value:
                model: user_component,
                as: 'UserComponents'
                where: {
                    active: 1
                },
                required: false,
                separate: true
            }, { // Adding components, filtered by "active" value:
                model: user_component,
                as: 'TenantComponents'
                where: {
                    active: 1
                },
                required: false,
                separate: true
            }]
        };
```

Please pay attention to **separate: true** option: this option tells sequielize to do separate queries for childs.
If you wish to get not all users but those ones with active only components (which ones: through user_id or tenant field?) you should set required: true in include. But in this case don't include both associations with required: true. This leads to miltiplication of amount of records in the result SQL query and consumes much more memory.

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately, after trying your proposal I am still getting child data unrelated to the specified user_id in the parent. Maybe this is a problem with the support for composite primary / foreign keys. Could this be the case?

Comment: This is it! Sequelize does not support composite foreign keys. See https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/311.

Comment: This is a huge dilema for me, since as I've researched, having this composite association is the easiest and safest way to implement multi-tenancy of data. It would be awesome to come up with a solution to make it work in Sequelize.